# Remove object that have an empty array value

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

So I have an object inside a `json` file like this:

```
{
    "0": {
        "damage_type": "Scratch",
        "regions": []
    },
    "1": {
        "damage_type": "Dent",
        "regions": []
    },
    "2": {
        "damage_type": "Dent",
        "regions": [
            "front side",
            "front window"
        ]
    }
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to remove the object that have empty `regions`. Like this:

```
{
    "2": {
        "damage_type": "Dent",
        "regions": [
            "front side",
            "front window"
        ]
    }
}
```

I am using a for loop and still unsuccessful:

```
jsonfile.readFile(theJsonFile, function (err, obj) {
    if (err) console.error(err)

    for (var i = 0; i <= Object.keys(obj).length - 1; i++) {
      if (obj[i].damage_type.length < 1) {
        delete obj[i]
      } 
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You're checking for the length of `damage_type`, not `regions`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling the parsed value `damages` instead of `obj`, you can grab all entries as key/value pairs, iterate over them and remove no-region "damages" by their ids:

```js
Object.entries(damages).forEach(([id, damage]) => {
  if (!damage.regions.length) {
    delete damages[id];
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you can create a brand new structure without touching the original structure:

```js
const entries = Object.entries(damages);
const filteredEntries = entries.filter(([_, damage]) => damage.regions.length);
const filteredDamages = Object.fromEntries(filteredEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case first you need  an array. To convert object to arrays use entry [entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```
let obj = {
    "0": {
        "damage_type": "Scratch",
        "regions": []
    },
    "1": {
        "damage_type": "Dent",
        "regions": []
    },
    "2": {
        "damage_type": "Dent",
        "regions": [
            "front side",
            "front window"
        ]
    }
}
```

converting array :

```
const myentry= Object.entries(obj);
```

Now the best way to eliminate or filter array is to use filter method and in return get the other object which have filter value.

[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
const myFiletrObj = myentry.filter(([_, obj]) => obj.regions.length).reduce(withObjectAssign, {})

function withObjectAssign(object, [key, value]) {
  return Object.assign(object, {[key]: value})
}
```

This will give you filtered output.

Answer (score 0):

made changes, try this

```
let json = {
    "0": {
        "damage_type": "Scratch",
        "regions": []
    },
    "1": {
        "damage_type": "Dent",
        "regions": []
    },
    "2": {
        "damage_type": "Dent",
        "regions": [
            "front side",
            "front window"
        ]
    }
};


function walk(obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
     let length = Object.keys(obj[key].regions).length; // get the length
     if(length==0){
       delete obj[key];
       
     }
  }
 console.log(json);
}
walk(json);
```

output

```
{ '2':
   { damage_type: 'Dent',
     regions: [ 'front side', 'front window' ]
 } 
}
```

Comment: @hisam if this is what you looking for, please upvote.

Answer (score -1):

You can delete a json node by its key

```
var json = { ... };
var key = "foo";
delete json[key]; // Removes json.foo from the dictionary.
```

Comment: The OP already seems to know how to delete a property. (Also, a nitpick: Don't name a JS data structure `json` unless it actually contains a JSON-stringified value. In your case, you're better off calling it `data`, `obj`, `value`, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

Why your code is not working?

You are incorrectly checking the condition for `damage_type.length` from each node. You need to delete the nodes with empty `regions`. So you have to check for `regions.length`.

**Your working Solution**

```js
const obj = { 
  "0": { "damage_type": "Scratch", "regions": [] },
  "1": { "damage_type": "Dent", "regions": [] },
  "2": { "damage_type": "Dent", "regions": [ "front side", "front window" ] }
};

for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj).length; i++) {
  if (!obj[i].regions || obj[i].regions.length === 0) {
    delete obj[i]
  } 
}
console.log(obj);
```

This solution works only because that the key of objects are same as the index "0", "1" and "2". If the key is something else, this wont work.

**Corrected solution**

Get the keys using `Object.keys` and delete the correct node.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const obj = { 
  "0": { "damage_type": "Scratch", "regions": [] },
  "1": { "damage_type": "Dent", "regions": [] },
  "2": { "damage_type": "Dent", "regions": [ "front side", "front window" ] }
};
const keys = Object.keys(obj);
for (var i = 0; i <= keys.length - 1; i++) {
  if (!obj[keys[i]].regions || obj[keys[i]].regions.length === 0) {
    delete obj[keys[i]]
  } 
}
console.log(obj);
```

**Generic Solution**

Get the key value combination using `Object.entries`

```js
const obj = { 
  "0": { "damage_type": "Scratch", "regions": [] },
  "1": { "damage_type": "Dent", "regions": [] },
  "2": { "damage_type": "Dent", "regions": [ "front side", "front window" ] }
};
const entries = Object.entries(obj);
entries.forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (!value.regions || value.regions.length === 0) {
    delete obj[key]
  }
})
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: You probably want `Object.entries(data)` to use the actual keys. With your example, it's just luck that the values will be indexed the same way as the original object's keys.

Comment: Yeah `Object.entries(data)` or `Object.keys` will do the trick irrespective of the values for key.

Comment: Calling `data[key]` twice is still sub-par to using `Object.entries()` to get both the key and value at the same time. Also, the OP doesn't seem to have a need to check if the `regions` property exists.

Comment: @AtesGoral agreed Updated the answer with `Object.entries()`. OP needs to delete nodes with empty region. So the `regions` key needs to be validated for the delete condition